# MyBatis - UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and useGeneratedKeys not working as expected

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People] 
(
    PersonId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Mapper:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Person" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="PersonId" keyProperty="personId">
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[People]
    (
        Name
    )
    VALUES
    (
        #{name}
    )
</insert>
```

Really simple:

I have a SQL Server 2008 db with a simple table that includes a GUID as the primary key. I want to return said GUID for any Person object inserted into the database. However, for whatever reason, it is returning  null when I look at the personId of my Person object.

Now - If I change the PersonId to a IDENTIFIER/Long/BitInt, this works completely. It is obviously related to the GUID, but I cannot figure out why. Is this an issue with MyBatis?

Project:

- Spring boot 2.3
- MyBatis Spring 2.1.1
- SQL Server driver 8.4.1.jre11

Comment: Reading the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-auto-generated-keys?view=sql-server-ver15), `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is not considered to be auto-generated, I would think (the value is set by specifying `DEFAULT`, right?). You may have to generate and set a UUID in Java code before insert.

Comment: Good catch - Have to investigate. I would prefer not putting the ID assignment on the Java side. I'll look at that doc and see what else potentially I could use (currently just going to role with BIGINT). Thanks for that link.